# How do I check my depth on OS X?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I know that if you want to check your depth on a PC, you press <kbd>F3</kbd>, but on my Mac, pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> brings up Mission Control and/or the Dashboard.

Is there a way to check depth in OS X without manually counting blocks?

Comment: see if you can turn/rebind that shortcut on your mac (add a meta key to it)

Answer (score 13):

> The debug screen is triggered when the <kbd>F3</kbd> key is pressed (**<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> on Macs** and some laptops).

—[Debug screen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen), Minecraft Wiki

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer to not always have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> when you press <kbd>F3</kbd> then you can reverse the setting so that you press <kbd>fn</kbd> with a function key to perform the standard OS X task (i.e. Mission Control would be <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>).

[image: System Preferences option]

System Preferences > Keyboard > Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.

Answer (score 3):

You need press the fn key and F3 simultaneously

If you press shift Fn and F3 it won't show the graph and pie chart.

Comment: Hi Albano, welcome to the site! Please only add an answer if it adds significantly more information over an existing one (we hate duplication here). If you can improve an existing answer by all means edit it - you'll gain reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

I have the same set up and got it to work today.

Comment: You don't need the control key: just fn and F3.