# How do i know how deep I am in minecraft for the MacBook Pro?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check my depth on OS X?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62644/how-do-i-check-my-depth-on-os-x)

I know that if you press F3, you can see the coordinates, but i'm on the mac and whenever I press F3, all it does is shows all the windows i'm on. For example Mail, Minecraft, Safari, Calendar. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried pushing and holding the "fn" key in the lower left corner and then pressing the "f3" key?

Typically the function key will allow you to use the alternate function of a button while the "fn" key is pressed down.

Give that a try and see if that works.